# Dynamically adding Panels into grid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I want to add panels dynamically into grid based on some count in wpf. But not in code behind or programatically. Using xaml only i need to create panels into grid dynamically. Is there any framework to do this?. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Using a ViewModel from the MVVM pattern, create an ObservableCollection and bind the ItemsSource for an ItemsControl to the ObservableCollection.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
  public ViewModel() { Objects = new ObservableCollection<object>(); }

  public ObservableCollection<object> Objects { get;set; }
}
```

Then in the View:

```
<Grid>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Objects}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Panel />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Then in the codebehind on the view:

```
DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

This will create one panel per item in your ObservableCollection.